# How to show PIL Image in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, python-imaging-library, jupyter-notebook

This is my code

```
from PIL import Image
pil_im = Image.open('data/empire.jpg')
```

I would like to do some image manipulation on it, and then show it on screen.
I am having problem with showing PIL Image in python notebook.

I have tried:

```
print pil_im
```

And just

```
pil_im
```

But both just give me:

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=569x800 at 0x10ECA0710>
```

Comment: do you want to show the image for preview, or you want to show inline image?

Comment: inline, after the cell

Comment: See also [How can I display an image from a file in in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854847/display-an-image-from-a-file-in-an-ipython-notebook).

Answer (score 364, accepted):

### Updated 2021/11/17

When using PIL/Pillow, Jupyter Notebooks now have a `display` built-in that will show the image directly, with no extra fuss.

```
display(pil_im)
```

Jupyter will also show the image if it is simply the last line in a cell (this has changed since the original post). Thanks to answers from [@Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64537316/213525) and [@Prabhat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470127/213525) for pointing this out.

### Other Methods

#### From File

You can also use IPython's `display` module to load the image. You can read more from [the doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image).

```
from IPython.display import Image 
pil_img = Image(filename='data/empire.jpg')
display(pil_img)
```

#### From PIL.Image Object

As OP's requirement is to use `PIL`, if you want to show inline image, you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` with `numpy.asarray` like this too:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

%matplotlib inline
pil_im = Image.open('data/empire.jpg', 'r')
imshow(np.asarray(pil_im))
```

If you only require a preview rather than an inline, you may just use `show` like this:

```
pil_im = Image.open('data/empire.jpg', 'r')
pil_im.show()
```

Comment: Do not import anything from `IPython.core` it is not stable api, we expose the stable api directly in `IPython.display`. I edited the post myself.

Comment: you are displaying image from file. I asked from PIL like in my example `pil_im`

Comment: @Matt, thanks for clarifying this. Although I've never run into problem using `core`, glad I've learnt a new thing :)

Comment: @WebOrCode, I've updated my answer to provide solutions using `PIL` as requested in OP.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem for now, but we reserve the right to move things in core somewhere else, at least the things in `core` exposed in `display`. and it's shorter to type :-)

Comment: @zhangxaochen, I guess it's because you're not assigning Image.open() to any name, and notebook is smart enough to preview the image for you. You can instantiate the image without opening omitting .open - I'm away from my laptop so please try and let me know your updates. I may update my answer with additional info if required

Comment: @Anzel, Yes I'm just asking if ipython has any one-liner magic to show the image object inline conviniently. ps: `PIL.Image` is a module, not a callable. And if you mean `IPython.display.Image`, it's saying: `Cannot embed the 'gif' image format`

Comment: @zhangxaochen, right I see I misunderstood your question before. I meant `Ipython.display.Image` and it currently only supports **png/jpg/jpeg**. So no, there is no one liner shortcut natively from Ipython afaik.

Comment: Stable docs here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html

Comment: @Anzel you could add that `display(im)` actually displays the image. The docs you linked don't contain this bit of info either.

Comment: @Avio ah interesting I’ve never used it like that. Please feel free to make edits, I’d happily approve and thanks for your info.

Comment: Edited. It was not showing any image, probably because I was doing it in a for loop...

Comment: @Avio, excellent. Perhaps take a few screenshots to show what each scenario will output? Don’t worry if it would require much of your time. I can pick a time to do those and attach under each case.

Comment: @Anzel could you clarify this? "If you only require a preview rather than an inline". How else a notebook can show an image besides inlining it? `pil_im.show()` does not do anything in my case. `IPython.display.display` works though.

Comment: @greatvovan that preview is to whoever using ipython notebook —no-browser for instance (or jupyter for newer version), not necessarily have to have the web browser, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Anzel I see thanks. I forgot that there was a time people used notebooks without a browser :)

Comment: @greatvovan yeah and I am one of those who likes to stick with terminal as much as possible :-)

Answer (score 78):

Use IPython display to render PIL images in a notebook.

```
from PIL import Image               # to load images
from IPython.display import display # to display images

pil_im = Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')
display(pil_im)
```

Comment: and if you just want to quickly inspect an image, you can just "return" it, to see its value, and it will be displayed automatically

Comment: This is so much simpler than other answers -- there's no need to convert to BytesIO or numpy array.

Comment: also it must be more performant (unless the interpreter understands that the data is being transcribed back and fourth)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work in a colab notebook :-/

Comment: this is the simplest approach - thanks for breaking out just the display object from IPython and the Image from PIL.
i was using PIL to create an image from weird data, and just wanted to display it in my notebook - this worked beautifully and simply.

Answer (score 26):

I found that this is working

```
# source: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/deeplook/5162445
from io import BytesIO

from IPython import display
from PIL import Image


def display_pil_image(im):
   """Displayhook function for PIL Images, rendered as PNG."""

   b = BytesIO()
   im.save(b, format='png')
   data = b.getvalue()

   ip_img = display.Image(data=data, format='png', embed=True)
   return ip_img._repr_png_()


# register display func with PNG formatter:
png_formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['image/png']
dpi = png_formatter.for_type(Image.Image, display_pil_image)
```

After this I can just do:

```
pil_im
```

But this must be last line in cell, with no `print` after it

Comment: You can use display.display to display the display.Image you created immediately, avoiding the dependency on being last in the cell: display.display(ip_img). You can see this used here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mandelbrot

Comment: @DavidF no, it seems as if you can't.  Trying all permutations of above.  How does one show an image in the notebook?

Comment: @DavidF Thanks, I was able to also use `display.display(i)`.

Comment: @Chris use the imports, function, and register calls. Then generate an image, `img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color = 'red')`, and then in a code cell run `display.display(img)` and you should see a small red rectangle printed to the notebook.

Answer (score 19):

much simpler in jupyter using pillow.

```
from PIL import Image
image0=Image.open('image.png')
image0
```

Answer (score 17):

case python3

```
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import HTML
from io import BytesIO
from base64 import b64encode

pil_im = Image.open('data/empire.jpg')
b = BytesIO()  
pil_im.save(b, format='png')
HTML("<img src='data:image/png;base64,{0}'/>".format(b64encode(b.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: It is showing the image in its original size. e.g If image is 32x32, then output will also be very small. How to give the size manually in HTML function?

Comment: @PramodPatil Easy soln: paste `style=\"width:100px; height:100px;\"` in between `<img` and `src`

Answer (score 10):

In order to simply visualize the image in a notebook you can use display()

```
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(im_path)
display(im)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can open an image using the Image class from the package PIL and display it with plt.imshow directly.

```
# First import libraries.
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The folliwing line is useful in Jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline

# Open your file image using the path
img = Image.open(<path_to_image>)

# Since plt knows how to handle instance of the Image class, just input your loaded image to imshow method
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the pylab extension, you could convert the image to a numpy array and use matplotlib's imshow.

```
%pylab # only if not started with the --pylab option
imshow(array(pil_im))
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, the pylab module is deprecated, so use the matplotlib magic instead and import the function explicitly:

```
%matplotlib
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow 
imshow(array(pil_im))
```

Comment: pylab is deprecated, do not use.

Answer (score 2):

Based on other answers and my tries, best experience would be first installing, *pillow* and scipy, then using the following starting code on your jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from scipy.misc import imread

imshow(imread('image.jpg', 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner Python3 version that use standard numpy, matplotlib and PIL. Merging the answer for opening from URL.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pil_im = Image.open('image.jpg')
## Uncomment to open from URL
#import requests
#r = requests.get('https://www.vegvesen.no/public/webkamera/kamera?id=131206')
#pil_im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
im_array = np.asarray(pil_im)
plt.imshow(im_array)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
from IPython.display import Image 
Image('image.png')
```

Comment: Your answer is correct in showing an image but as OP wants to use PIL to modify the image further, it sort of doesn't answer the question directly.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest following installation by no image show img.show() 
(from PIL import Image)

$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick