# Image not loading (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to load an image to Jupyter notebook to use it in Tensorflow, Im using this Code below :

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path    
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import sklearn.model_selection as train_test_split    
import tensorflow as tf    
from PIL import Image    
import os    
from keras.utils import to_categorical    
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense,Flatten, Dropout 



data= []    
labels = []    
classes = 43    
cur_path = os.getcwd()

for i in range(classes) :     
    path = os.path.join(cur_path,'Dataset\Train', str(i))    
    images = os.listdir(path)

for a in images :        
    try: 
        image = Image.open(path + '\\'  + a)    
        image.resize(30,30)    
        image.show()    
        image = np.array(image)    
        data.append(image)    
        labels.append(i)

    except:    
        print("error loading image")

data = np.array(data)    
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Unfortunately im having this error message :`error loading image`
Does anyone have any idea?

Update : Removed the try and except ,

for a in images :

```
 image = Image.open(path + '\\' + a) 

 image.resize(30,30) 

 display(image) 

 image = np.array(image) 

 data = np.array(data) 

 labels = np.array(labels)
```

error  :

ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2
3         image = Image.open(path + '\'  + a)

----> 4         image.resize(30,30)

```
  5         display(image)

  6         image = np.array(image)
```

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in resize(self, size, resample, box, reducing_gap)
1883                 )
1884             ]
-> 1885             raise ValueError(

1886                 message + " Use " + ", ".join(filters[:-1]) + " or " +
filters[-1]

1887             )

ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (30). Use Image.NEAREST (0),

Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or

Image.HAMMING (5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show PIL Image in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649716/how-to-show-pil-image-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Tried it, but I got the same error again.

Comment: Possibly something to do with Image.resize, updated the code fragment above

Answer (score 0):

Solved the value error after a few changes:

```
from IPython.display import display

for a in images :   

  try:
     image = Image.open(path + '\\'  + a)
     image = image.resize((30,30))
     display(image)
     image = np.array(image)
     data.append(image)
     labels.append(i)
  except: 
     print("error loading image")

data = np.array(data)

labels = np.array(labels)
```

**Thankyou basic mojo **