# How can I display image data in Jupyter notebook AND control its position?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I don't understand why I cannot find any examples on this, maybe its not possible; I've seen [How to show PIL Image in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649716/how-to-show-pil-image-in-ipython-notebook) and [How to convert a NumPy array to PIL image applying matplotlib colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965417/how-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap) and cannot figure this out.

Say I have this Jupyter code:

```py
import io

import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(facecolor=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
fig.text(0, 0, "Hello World", fontsize=20)
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=120, format="png", bbox_inches="tight",
                pad_inches=0)
    buf.seek(0)
    rgba = plt.imread(buf)


from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown as md, Javascript, HTML

display(md("I want this text **above** the image"))

plt.imshow(rgba)

display(md("I want this text **below** the image"))
```

This is what I get:

[image]

... but this is what I want instead:

[image]

... or in case I'm not clear enough, this is the end result I desire:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: In addition to the example I posted that changes least amount in your code, you could have saved the plot of the array as an image to a file and used `from IPython.display import Image` combined with `display(Image(<image_file>))` to display the result sandwiched between your two markdown text lines.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to control the output plot differently so that you don't let Jupyter separate it out from the display commands:

```py
import io

import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(facecolor=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
fig.text(0, 0, "Hello World", fontsize=20)
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=120, format="png", bbox_inches="tight",
                pad_inches=0)
    buf.seek(0)
    rgba = plt.imread(buf)


from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
im = plt.imshow(rgba)
plt.close() # from https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-hide-a-figure-from-being-shown-in-matplotlib-in-python

display(md("I want this text **above** the image"))

display(im.figure)

display(md("I want this text **below** the image"))
```

Explanation:
It uses `plt.close()` to hide what normally jupyter would display as the result of `plt.imshow(rgba)` separate from the output of the display functions in the code.
Then we can use the handle it was assigned to, `im`, to call the figure attribute of `im` inside a `display` function sandwiched between the other two display commands.

Demonstration option:
That code will work when pasted in new notebooks opened from inside Jupyter sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder), served via MyBinder.org.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `plt.show()` when you want to display the plot. So here after the instruction `plt.imshow(rgba)`