# How do I print an image from a link in console?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How do I print an image from a link in console?

The image link is "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/826439366439993354/c107a313dba5b75dd388c2fca5df68f9.png", I know I can print this using the pillow module if I download the .png, but how would I do this if it's not downloaded? Is there any way to do this without downloading the image, just printing it in the console?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't show an image without downloading it first. Either you download it, or a library you use will do it, but either way, it has to be downloaded first. So, what do you mean? You want a function that does it (download then print) for you? Or you want to save disk and download it in memory only?

Comment: I want it to use that picture from a URL only once without downloading it? If that's impossible, how do I make it download the picture, print it and delete it?

Comment: You have to *download* the image, but you can avoid *saving* it to a file.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Furkan's answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BytesIO`

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/164/164372.png"
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
display(img)
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything, no errors, no nothing. What should I do? I am doing the following: response = requests.get(pfpurl)
        print(response.content)
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) .... Is that because the image address is different or does that not matter?

Comment: You have to write display(img) to end of the code, can you try this?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I edited the code block, please try with it. It has to work.

Comment: I get the following error: "AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'" for the line: " img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))"

Comment: Then you must have redfined/shadowed `Image` previously in your code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: You must have defined your own variable named `Image`. The `Image` imported from `PIL` *does* have an `open` attribute.

Comment: Fixed, now I get "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000000003A70770>"

Comment: @FurkanAkdag manually wrapping with `BytesIO` isn't actually necessary anymore.

Comment: @container Can you try to change the importing of PIL => import PIL.Image and change the img part as =>  img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

Comment: @CrazyChucky I did not know that, this code block works anyway :D

Comment: It does, sure. But you can remove the `BytesIO` and just use `response.raw`. Pillow handles the rest automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40944159/12975140

Comment: I get "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000000003AF0950>"

Comment: Well that's definitely strange. I can open that URL in a browser, but it appears Pillow isn't recognizing it as a valid image.

Comment: Yeah same, maybe it's because it has a different image address?

Comment: What do you mean "different image address"?

Comment: Actually the code block works on my local and the image is displayed on my PyCharm

Comment: I am trying to load the following url: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/826439366439993354/c107a313dba5b75dd388c2fca5df68f9.png" and it gives me that error, if you right click and click copy image address, it's something different.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you get the image:
[How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

And this should help you display it: [How to show PIL Image in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649716/how-to-show-pil-image-in-ipython-notebook)