# IPython Notebook cell multiple outputs

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am running this cell in IPython Notebook:

```
# salaries and teams are Pandas dataframe
salaries.head()
teams.head()
```

The result is that I am only getting the output of `teams` data-frame rather than of both `salaries` and `teams`. If I just run `salaries.head()` I get the result for `salaries` data-frame but on running both the statement I just see the output of `teams.head()`. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

have you tried the `display` command?

```
from IPython.display import display
display(salaries.head())
display(teams.head())
```

Comment: From the docs: "Since IPython 5.4 and 6.1 `display()` is automatically made available to the user without import."

Comment: I am using IPython 6.4.0 and I had to use the import statement 
`from IPython.display import display`

Answer (score 153):

An easier way:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

It saves you having to repeatedly type "Display"

Say the cell contains this:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

a = 1
b = 2

a
b
```

Then the output will be:

```
Out[1]: 1
Out[1]: 2
```

If we use `IPython.display.display`:

```
from IPython.display import display

a = 1
b = 2

display(a)
display(b)
```

The output is:

```
1
2
```

So the same thing, but without the `Out[n]` part.

Comment: Is this new?
I don't recall seeing this option a couple of years ago.

Comment: I don't even see it in the updated documentation: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell

But is on the "Terminal" IPython options: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html

Comment: Oh man, I wish I could answer that. I remember seeing it on a different question months ago (I wish I could source) and it worked perfectly for me so I've kept it in my back pocket.

Comment: Would be nice adding what will this behave like, will it display for every and each line?

Comment: @matanster I can add that to the main answer. But it displays each expression while assigning the same "Out[x]:" to each. See answer for more clarity

Comment: You should be using `get_ipython().ast_node_interactivity = 'all'`, not replacing the class property with an constant string!

Comment: Not surprising `from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell` does not work in Colab. Anybody knows how to enable multiple outputs in Colab ?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62736001/5289570) to make this config change common across all notebooks

Comment: It's worth noting that only the last output is [saved](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system), regardless of how this setting is set.

Comment: @Eric Or `c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"` in a [config file](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#python-configuration-files). The similar syntax is kind of confusing — just the extra `c.` at the start.

Answer (score 8):

Enumerating all the solutions:

- [`sys.displayhook(value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), which IPython/jupyter hooks into. Note this behaves slightly differently from calling `display`, as it includes the `Out[n]` text. This works fine in regular python too!
- [`display(value)`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402423/102441)
- [`get_ipython().ast_node_interactivity = 'all'`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity). This is similar to but better than the approach taken by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476224/102441).

Comparing these in an interactive session:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: display(1)          # appears without Out
   ...: sys.displayhook(2)  # appears with Out
   ...: 3                   # missing
   ...: 4                   # appears with Out
1
Out[2]: 2
Out[2]: 4

In [3]: get_ipython().ast_node_interactivity = 'all'

In [2]: display(1)          # appears without Out
   ...: sys.displayhook(2)  # appears with Out
   ...: 3                   # appears with Out (different to above)
   ...: 4                   # appears with Out
1
Out[4]: 2
Out[4]: 3
Out[4]: 4
```

Note that the behavior in Jupyter is exactly the same as it is in ipython.

Comment: How do we reset it to exhibit the original behaviour once invoked by setting ast_node_interactivity to 'all'?

Comment: Asked too quickly!! it should be set to `get_ipython().ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr'` to revert to the default behaviour.

Other possible options are 'none', 'last' and 'last_expr_or_assign'.

Comment: *"as it includes the `Out[n]` text"* - Not just that, it also [saves the result](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system), though only the last result if there are multiple. For me, I want to show a Pandas dataframe then its dtypes from the same cell and save the dataframe, so I do `df` then `display(df.dtypes)`.

Answer (score 5):

IPython Notebook shows only the last return value in a cell. The easiest solution for your case is to use two cells.

If you really need only one cell you could do a **hack** like this:

```
class A:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return salaries.head()._repr_html_() + '</br>' + teams.head()._repr_html_()

A()
```

If you need this often, make it a function:

```
def show_two_heads(df1, df2, n=5):
    class A:
        def _repr_html_(self):
            return df1.head(n)._repr_html_() + '</br>' + df2.head(n)._repr_html_()
    return A()
```

Usage:

```
show_two_heads(salaries, teams)
```

A version for more than two heads:

```
def show_many_heads(*dfs, n=5):
    class A:
        def _repr_html_(self):
            return  '</br>'.join(df.head(n)._repr_html_() for df in dfs) 
    return A()
```

Usage:

```
show_many_heads(salaries, teams, df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide,

```
print salaries.head()
teams.head()
```

Comment: Nice but output of `print salaries.head()` is not well formatted.

Comment: use display() as for print output will not be well formatted.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you use the print function since giving direct commands only returns the output of last command.
For instance,

```
salaries.head()
teams.head()
```

outputs **only for teams.head()**

while,

```
print(salaries.head())
print(teams.head())
```

outputs for **both the commands.**

So, basically, **use the print() function**