# Output Format in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently using `Jupyter Notebook` for my study purposes. I have [follow this guide](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python)  on Pandas DataFrame by `Datacamp`

I'm curious about one thing with Jupyter notebook:

**I have the following segment of code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [40, 50, 60], [23, 35, 37]]),
              index=[2.5, 12.6, 4.8, 4.8, 2.5],
              columns=[48, 49, 50])

print(df)
print('-------------------')

df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last').set_index('index')
```

**Output**

[image: output]

I notice that my first `print()` function will return the table before the separating line. However, the line of code below, which is `df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index',keep='last').set_index('index')` will return a pretty-looking table below.

I want to to the same thing with `print(df)` by trying to remove the whole function `print(df)` and go to a new line and type in `df`. The result is that i will be able to create the same format as shown.

**However**, I can't recreate the same format if I just remove the section `print(df)` and replace it with `df` in the same block of codes.

**My question is**:

1. Are there any way to create the same format within the same block of code?

Comment: Is it just me or the image link is broken?

Comment: I think it is only you I guess, but never mind i will give you [the link](https://i.imgur.com/qgPdPlX.png)

Comment: @aarnphm I also have a problem with the image. It reads "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available", both in your post and after clicking your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these 2 lines to the top of your notebook:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

If this doesn't work, you might find an answer here:
[IPython Notebook cell multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398054/ipython-notebook-cell-multiple-outputs)