# How to show row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict of datarames `dict_of_dfs`.

I try two show first row from each dataset:

```
for colsKey, colsValue in dict_of_cols.items():
    dict_of_dfs['dt_'+str(colsKey)] = pd.DataFrame(colsValue)

for dfName, val in dict_of_dfs.items():
    row = dict_of_dfs[dfName].head(1)
    row
```

But it does not work for me.

This also does not return me output pandas frame:

```
for dfName in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    dict_of_dfs['dt_12'].head(1).to_string()
```

Comment: Add a `print`statement: `print(row)`

Comment: Yes, it works but I see that like plain text not a frame

Comment: But this gives me right output:

`dict_of_dfs['dt_12'].head(1)`

Comment: Maybe head() can not work in loop?

Comment: if you are working in a jupyter notebook use `display()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPython Notebook cell multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398054/ipython-notebook-cell-multiple-outputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working in Jupyter Notebook. You can use the `display` function from `IPython.display`.

```py
from IPython.display import display
for dfName, val in dict_of_dfs.items():
    display(val.head(1))
```