# Jupyter html image does not change when file is replaced

Tags: html, image, markdown, python-3.5, jupyter-notebook

In an Jupyter notebook markdown cell I evaluate

```
<img src="mypic.png">
```

which displays the pic in the notebook. If I replace the file mypic.png and evaluate the above command again, the displayed image remains the old. 
The same happens if include the picture using markdown, like

```
![mypic](mypic.png)
```

To change the displayed image I have to either restart the kernel or change the filename and include the pic with new filename, like `![mypic(mypic_.png)`.
What's the problem here and how do I solve it?

Comment: The image is being cached by your browser. One way to avoid it is to use `IPython.display.Image('mypic.png')` - this will read it from disk and send the data to the browser to display. It will mean that the notebook file includes a copy of the image, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename="mypic.png")
```

Learned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855133/828184)

Note that this does not display the image inside a loop and your markdown cell must become a code cell