# How do I add an image to my python stock prediction web app that I am hosting locally through streamlit?

Tags: python

This is because I have tried using the code below but when I run my web app no image is displayed.
Note that this program is written on notepad++
,,,

```
    #import the libraries.
    import streamlit as st
    import pandas as pd

    # insert Image.
    from IPython.display import Image
    Image("Desktop\stock.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do the following:**

Make sure that the path of the image is the same as the path of the project folder and work on fixing the code for displaying the image

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='test.png')
```

If the solution does not work, try to go to this question
ref:
[How can I display an image from a file in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854847/how-can-i-display-an-image-from-a-file-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Can you explain ***why*** this solves the problem? According to [the docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image), calling without the keyword will pass the argument to `data` which says: *"The raw image data or a URL or filename to load the data from"* so it seems to be fine

Comment: I modified the answer, I think it answers your request. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To display images in Streamlit, you can use `st.image`:

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=image#streamlit.image

```
import streamlit as st

st.image('sunrise.jpg')

#or, if you are processing the bytes

from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('sunrise.jpg')

st.image(image, caption='Sunrise by the mountains')
```