# tiff images visually different when visualized in ipynb and standard image viewer in MacBook Pro

Tags: python, tiff

I have a `.tiff` file/image. When I use the following code to visualize it inline in a python notebook, it looks like the following. Code and image shown below -

```
orig_img_path = os.path.join("/path/to/tiff/1000.tiff")
img_orig = Image.open(orig_img_path,"r")
img_arr = np.array(img_orig) 
min_pix, max_pix = np.amin(img_arr), np.amax(img_arr)
plt.imshow(img_arr, vmin = min_pix, vmax = max_pix, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

The image looks like the following -

[image]

Whereas the same image when viewed through the standard image viewer on my MacBook looks like so -

[image]

I am wondering why is there so much difference between the images when viewed through different methods. It seems like the one which is viewed through ipynb is much grayer than the one which viewed through simply on Mac.

Thanks and please let me know if I am missing anything.

-- Megh

Comment: Check the range and `dtype` of your pixels `print(min_pix, max_pix, img_arr.dtype)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Tiff images in ipynb or jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73424132/displaying-tiff-images-in-ipynb-or-jupyter-notebook)